# Specifying a database in JDBC URL for Netezza

Tags: jdbc, netezza

When connecting to [Netezza via JDBC](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.datacon.doc/r_datacon_jdbc_connection_string.html), the database in the URL is a required field - e.g. the value `sales` in the example URL  `jdbc:netezza://main:5490/sales;user=admin;password=password`

The first time I connect to a Netezza instance, I don't (necessarily) know the name of a database on the appliance. Guessing a database name is a very time consuming exercise.

In this scenario, what value should I provide? Is there a "use default" option, a way to list databases, or a specific database name that will always work (e.g. a system database)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netezza will always have one main database: system.
You cannot delete the system database. 
I would suggest that you connect to `jdbc:netezza://hostname:5480/system`.

Once connected, you can list the databases that your user has access to, using

```
select database
from _v_database;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer definitively, but it appears that every Netezza appliance *by default* has a database named `TESTDB`. This is at least true for all the appliances to which I have access.

Users or administrators may be able to delete this database, but it's a good bet if you need a database to which to connect.